# SignInWithAppleButton check for value before starting authorisation

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am creating a signup flow with swiftui, with two options: email+pass or Apple Login.

The user needs to accept T&C (via checkbox) before being able to Sign Up. This works flawlessly in the email+pass signup, but I have not been able to add the same check within the `SignInWithAppleButton` methods, so that it runs before the user starts the actual Apple flow.

This is the form
[image: Signup Form]

And this is the code I currently have for the Button

```swift
SignInWithAppleButton(.signIn) { request in
  request.requestedScopes = [.email]
} onCompletion: { result in
  switch result {
    case .success(let authResults):
       // My code
    case .failure(let error):
      print("Authorisation failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
  }
}
```

I've already successfully tested my check within the `onCompletion` part, but this is not ideal from the UX perspective, since the user needs first to complete the Apple Sign up, just to be reminded they didn't select the checkbox.

So instead, I tried adding my check after `request.requestedScopes = [.email]`, and the check itself works, but I am not able to stop the next step from happening since `request` doesn't have a `cancel()` or `stop()` method.

I also tried attaching the event `onTapGesture`, but in this case I am not able to start the Apple flow if the check is passed.

So, my question is: **how can I check that the checkbox is checked BEFORE the actual Apple login flows start?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the button as long as the checkbox is unchecked:

```
@State private var termsAccepted: Bool = false

var body: some View{
    SignInWithAppleButton{ _ in
        
    } onCompletion: { _ in
        
    }
    .disabled(!termsAccepted) // disable the button here
}
```

### Edit:

You could add a conditional overlay to capture a tap:

```
@State private var termsAccepted: Bool = false

var body: some View{
    VStack{

        Toggle("terms", isOn: $termsAccepted)
        SignInWithAppleButton{ _ in
            
        } onCompletion: { _ in
            
        }
        .disabled(!termsAccepted)
        .overlay{
            if !termsAccepted{
                Color.clear
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print("please accept terms")
                    }
                    
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This is nice, thanks for this it's very simple and elegant. 

But in addition I'd love to show an error message to the user, like "You need to accept the terms" if you click and it's not checked. Is it possible to integrate it in the same logic?

Comment: @AndreaOlivato please see my updated answer.